# Ubuntu Windows Dual boot on the same drive problem

Tags: windows

I installed ubuntu along with windows . How can i see the files downloaded by ubuntu o.s in  windows o.s

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Windows doesn't support ext4 at all. You could copy them across to Windows from Ubuntu, or you could try ext2fs on Windows.

Comment: @VickyRohilla Or you can download them into NTFS windows patition